# Cannot connect Optimism-mainnet Infura with web3.py

Tags: web3.py, infura, python

I am trying to connect Optimism-mainnet with web3.py but it always shows `False`

Here is my script

```
from web3 import Web3

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://optimism-mainnet.infura.io/v3/myid'))

print(w3.isConnected())
```

I tried in Windows and Ubuntu both, but still got same error.

Kindly help me in connecting

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try executing some command? Like getting an address balance for example.

Comment: I don't think it will work as I am not connected to web3. But let me try.

Comment: I tried running `w3.eth.get_balance('0xd3CdA913deB6f67967B99D67aCDFa1712C293601')` and got this error `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://optimism-mainnet.infura.io/v3/{myid}` @Ismael

Comment: When I try this with other networks, it works. Only Optimism is not working. Can't understand, why.

Comment: If it works for other networks then the code is fine so I'd check with infura if there's some outage.